# Проброс портов на Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, iptables, raspberry-pi

На Raspberry Pi3 есть следующие сетевые интерфейсы:

```
~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.4.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.4.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe6c:46b6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:6c:46:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4877  bytes 425607 (415.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6278  bytes 1276564 (1.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4980  bytes 462816 (451.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4980  bytes 462816 (451.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.46.154.155  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.64.64.64
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 973  bytes 161883 (158.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1125  bytes 466589 (455.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.14.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.10.14.5
        inet6 fe80::1a48:3d1b:26e9:af82  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 269  bytes 14687 (14.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 270  bytes 333665 (325.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:39:13:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Интернет малина получает через 3G-модем, это соединение ppp0. Затем поднимается соединение OpenVPN (tun0). IP адрес малина получает всегда один и тот-же.
На интерфейсе eth0 руками настроен только IP адрес 192.168.4.5. (Нет gateway)
К eth0 подключен видеорегистратор со статическим IP 192.168.4.200 и слушает порт 85.
Задача: Настроить проброс порта (например 8585) интерфейса tun0 на порт 85 интерфейса eth0
Чтобы я на удалённом устройстве набирая http://10.10.14.6:8585 попадал на 192.168.4.200:85
Iptables пробовал следующие настройки:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.10.14.6 --dport 8585 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.200:85
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 85 --dst 192.168.4.200 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.14.6:8585

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 8585 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.200:85

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8585 -i tun0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.200:85
```

Всё тщетно, прошу помочь.

Вывод Iptables -L после всех настроек: (как я понял правил нет...)

```
~ $ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.68-v8+ #1587 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 20 11:18:43 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут правильно

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.10.14.6 --dport 8585 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.200:85
```

Дальше не нужно, отработает контрак, форвард и так открыт, но не включен. В файл /etc/sysctl.conf добавь

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Или скриптом

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Но нужно маскараднуть так как не понятно как шлюзить будет видик.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.4.200 -j MASQUERADE
```